# Magento 1.6 - Save an array from user input as a collection of models

Tags: php, magento, php-5.3

I'm implementing a user interface on the backend for adding an arbitrary number of values to a product - just like the price tier interface. I'd like to know how saving data like this is usually done.

Below is some simplified code of my attempt (which throws this error: Item with the same id "1" already exists"):

```
$myItemCollection = $product->getMyItemCollection();
if(!$myItemCollection) {
    $myItemCollection = Mage::getModel('my_module/my_item')->getCollection();
}

foreach($product->getMyData('items') as $data) {
    $myItem = Mage::getModel('my_module/my_item')->addData($data);
    // Item with the same id "1" already exist on the second iteration
    $myItemCollection->addItem($myItem);
}

$myItemCollection
    ->setDataToAll('product_id', $product->getId())
    ->save();
```

$product->getMyData('items') returns something like:

```
array(
    1 => array(
        'foo' => 'bar'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'bin' => 'baz'
    ),
    3 => array(
        'buz' => 'fuz'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collection uses the `getId()` method on the added item to get the array key for the internal `$_items` array. Your error *Item with the same id "1" already exist* on the second iteration means you are setting some value on the new models that is returned as an id value.

If `getId()` returns `null` the item is added using `$_items[] = $item` to the collection without that error being thrown.
This means if you are using standard models and resource models, `$data` probably doesn't match the array you posted.

The key that is used to return the ID value for a model depends on the type of entity.
If the model uses a EAV based resource model (`Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract`), the key is `entity_id`, e.g. `array('entity_id' => 1, 'foo' => 'bar')`.

If the model uses a flat table based resource model (`Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract`), the primary key field is (usually) set in the resource model's `_construct()` method, as the second parameter to the `_init()` call.
So if the resource model's initialization looks like `$this->_init('my_module/my_item', 'item_id')` the value to set on the `$data` array would be `array('item_id' => 1, 'foo' => 'bar')`.